# How saas app saml configuration fedaration works

Tags: authentication, saml, okta, saas

Situation:
I have a SaaS application.it has saml configuration page where users can add configuration to bring their own idp providers like okta, etc. It has information like login url response url. It is also configured as app in okta too.

Question :

Now a user login into my saas app. they just enter email id and click login. In the backend do i have to build a api to read this user federation url from the data store to redirect/authorize and to the app.

like if users from a@comp1.com logins then the api has to bring the federation url of the comp1 company and then redirect and if user b@comp2.com logins then url of comp2

Just when users enter email how can i identify which idp and configuration they have linked and redirect them to the respective url

is this how generally done in SaaS saml login experience ?

Comment: Usually SaaS apps have a tenant which has its own configuration for a user (or a group of users from the same company). So when your users is logging in, it's logging into their tenant determined by the URL https://tenant1.saasX.com

Comment: Thanks ,i have been told in the comp that once user does the configuration of saml they have remember the federation id and login with the federation id attached to the url.

Comment: In terms of SP initiated authentication do users have to remember special saas url or just login with email id to proceed to login with idp

Comment: It depends... Normally your SaaS should have a button or something visible to users of that tenant after SAML has been configured. They click there and got redirected to IdP with SAML authN request.